# My plot for punctuation and characters is just not coming up. Advice required

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

[BLANK IMAGE WHY!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndVE8.jpg)So I have tried running my code on Pycharm, spider simply not showing the plot. I am a newbie like a very newbie. Need your help here. The word plot actually shows up. The others well empty. I'll attach a picture.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import word_StudentID as ws
import preprocessor_StudentID as pre
import character_Student as cha
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class AnalysisVisualiser:

    def __init__(self, df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6):

        self.df_rich = open('Richard_II_Shakespeare.tok')
        self.df_Edw = open('Edward_II_Marlowe.tok')
        self.df_ham = open('Hamlet_Shakespeare.tok')
        self.df_hen1 = open('Henry_VI_Part1_Shakespeare.tok')
        self.df_hen2 = open('Henry_VI_Part2_Shakespeare.tok')
        self.df_jew = open('Jew_of_Malta_Marlowe.tok')


    def visualise_character_frequency(self):
        ob1 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob2 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob3 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob4 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob5 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob6 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ''' Processing the file'''        
        print("part 1")

        ob1.tokenise(self.df_rich)
        ob2.tokenise(self.df_Edw)
        ob3.tokenise(self.df_ham)
        ob4.tokenise(self.df_hen1)
        ob5.tokenise(self.df_hen2)
        ob6.tokenise(self.df_jew)
        ''' converting file into a line'''        
        print("part 2")

        token1 = ob1._tokenised_list()
        token2 = ob2._tokenised_list()
        token3 = ob3._tokenised_list()
        token4 = ob4._tokenised_list()
        token5 = ob5._tokenised_list()
        token6 = ob6._tokenised_list()
        ''''getting file in the form of list'''

        print("part 5")

        ob_cha1 = cha.CharacterAnalyser()
        ob_cha2 = cha.CharacterAnalyser()
        ob_cha3 = cha.CharacterAnalyser()
        ob_cha4 = cha.CharacterAnalyser()
        ob_cha5 = cha.CharacterAnalyser()
        ob_cha6 = cha.CharacterAnalyser()
        ''' Counting number of characters'''
        print("part 6")

        ac1 = ob_cha1.analyse_characters(token1)
        ac2 = ob_cha2.analyse_characters(token2)
        ac3 = ob_cha3.analyse_characters(token3)
        ac4 = ob_cha4.analyse_characters(token4)
        ac5 = ob_cha5.analyse_characters(token5)
        ac6 = ob_cha6.analyse_characters(token6)

        plt.plot(ac1['val'], ac1['frq'], label = 'Richard_II_Shakespeare')
        plt.plot(ac2['val'], ac2['frq'], label = 'Edward_II_Marlowe')
        plt.plot(ac3['val'], ac3['frq'], label = 'Hamlet_Shakespeare')
        plt.plot(ac4['val'], ac4['frq'], label = 'Henry_VI_Part1_Shakespeare')
        plt.plot(ac5['val'], ac5['frq'], label = 'Henry_VI_Part2_Shakespeare')
        plt.plot(ac6['val'], ac6['frq'], label = 'Jew_of_Malta_Marlowe')
        plt.title('character_frequency')
        plt.show()






    def visualise_punctuation_frequency(self):

        ob1 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob2 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob3 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob4 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob5 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob6 = pre.Preprocessor()

        print("part 1")

        ob1.tokenise(self.df_rich)
        ob2.tokenise(self.df_Edw)
        ob3.tokenise(self.df_ham)
        ob4.tokenise(self.df_hen1)
        ob5.tokenise(self.df_hen2)
        ob6.tokenise(self.df_jew)

        print("part 2")

        token1 = ob1._tokenised_list()
        token2 = ob2._tokenised_list()
        token3 = ob3._tokenised_list()
        token4 = ob4._tokenised_list()
        token5 = ob5._tokenised_list()
        token6 = ob6._tokenised_list()

        print("part 3")

        ob_ws1 = ws.WordAnalyser()
        ob_ws2 = ws.WordAnalyser()
        ob_ws3 = ws.WordAnalyser()
        ob_ws4 = ws.WordAnalyser()
        ob_ws5 = ws.WordAnalyser()
        ob_ws6 = ws.WordAnalyser()

        print("part 4")

        token1 = ob1._tokenised_list()
        token2 = ob2._tokenised_list()
        token3 = ob3._tokenised_list()
        token4 = ob4._tokenised_list()
        token5 = ob5._tokenised_list()
        token6 = ob6._tokenised_list()

        print("part 5")

        ob_cha1 = cha.CharacterAnalyser()
        ob_cha2 = cha.CharacterAnalyser()
        ob_cha3 = cha.CharacterAnalyser()
        ob_cha4 = cha.CharacterAnalyser()
        ob_cha5 = cha.CharacterAnalyser()
        ob_cha6 = cha.CharacterAnalyser()

        print("part 6")

        ob_cha1.analyse_characters(token1)
        ob_cha2.analyse_characters(token2)
        ob_cha3.analyse_characters(token3)
        ob_cha4.analyse_characters(token4)
        ob_cha5.analyse_characters(token5)
        ob_cha6.analyse_characters(token6)

        print("part 7")

        pun1 = ob_cha1.get_punctuation_frequency()
        pun2 = ob_cha2.get_punctuation_frequency()
        pun3 = ob_cha3.get_punctuation_frequency()
        pun4 = ob_cha4.get_punctuation_frequency()
        pun5 = ob_cha5.get_punctuation_frequency()
        pun6 = ob_cha6.get_punctuation_frequency()

        print("part 8")

        plt.plot(pun1['val'], pun1['frq'], label = 'Richard_II_Shakespeare')
        plt.plot(pun2['val'], pun2['frq'], label = 'Edward_II_Marlowe')
        plt.plot(pun3['val'], pun3['frq'], label = 'Hamlet_Shakespeare')
        plt.plot(pun4['val'], pun4['frq'], label = 'Henry_VI_Part1_Shakespeare')
        plt.plot(pun5['val'], pun5['frq'], label = 'Henry_VI_Part2_Shakespeare')
        plt.plot(pun6['val'], pun6['frq'], label = 'Jew_of_Malta_Marlowe')
        plt.title('punctuation_frequency')
        plt.show()








    def visualise_stopword_frequency(self):

        ob1 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob2 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob3 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob4 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob5 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob6 = pre.Preprocessor()

        print("part 1")

        ob1.tokenise(self.df_rich)
        ob2.tokenise(self.df_Edw)
        ob3.tokenise(self.df_ham)
        ob4.tokenise(self.df_hen1)
        ob5.tokenise(self.df_hen2)
        ob6.tokenise(self.df_jew)

        print("part 2")

        token1 = ob1._tokenised_list()
        token2 = ob2._tokenised_list()
        token3 = ob3._tokenised_list()
        token4 = ob4._tokenised_list()
        token5 = ob5._tokenised_list()
        token6 = ob6._tokenised_list()

        print("part 3")

        ob_ws1 = ws.WordAnalyser()
        ob_ws2 = ws.WordAnalyser()
        ob_ws3 = ws.WordAnalyser()
        ob_ws4 = ws.WordAnalyser()
        ob_ws5 = ws.WordAnalyser()
        ob_ws6 = ws.WordAnalyser()

        print("part 4")

        ob_ws1.analyse_word(token1)
        ob_ws2.analyse_word(token2)
        ob_ws3.analyse_word(token3)
        ob_ws4.analyse_word(token4)
        ob_ws5.analyse_word(token5)
        ob_ws6.analyse_word(token6)        


        stop1 = ob_ws1.get_stopword_frequency()
        stop2 = ob_ws2.get_stopword_frequency()
        stop3 = ob_ws3.get_stopword_frequency()
        stop4 = ob_ws4.get_stopword_frequency()
        stop5 = ob_ws5.get_stopword_frequency()
        stop6 = ob_ws6.get_stopword_frequency()

        plt.plot(stop1['val'], stop1['frq'], label = 'Richard_II_Shakespeare')
        plt.plot(stop2['val'], stop2['frq'], label = 'Edward_II_Marlowe')
        plt.plot(stop3['val'], stop3['frq'], label = 'Hamlet_Shakespeare')
        plt.plot(stop4['val'], stop4['frq'], label = 'Henry_VI_Part1_Shakespeare')
        plt.plot(stop5['val'], stop5['frq'], label = 'Henry_VI_Part2_Shakespeare')
        plt.plot(stop6['val'], stop6['frq'], label = 'Jew_of_Malta_Marlowe')
        plt.title('stopword_frequency')
        plt.show()





    def visualise_word_length_frequency(self):

        ob1 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob2 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob3 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob4 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob5 = pre.Preprocessor()
        ob6 = pre.Preprocessor()

        print("part 1")

        ob1.tokenise(self.df_rich)
        ob2.tokenise(self.df_Edw)
        ob3.tokenise(self.df_ham)
        ob4.tokenise(self.df_hen1)
        ob5.tokenise(self.df_hen2)
        ob6.tokenise(self.df_jew)

        print("part 2")

        token1 = ob1._tokenised_list()
        token2 = ob2._tokenised_list()
        token3 = ob3._tokenised_list()
        token4 = ob4._tokenised_list()
        token5 = ob5._tokenised_list()
        token6 = ob6._tokenised_list()

        print("part 3")


        ob_ws1 = ws.WordAnalyser()
        ob_ws2 = ws.WordAnalyser()
        ob_ws3 = ws.WordAnalyser()
        ob_ws4 = ws.WordAnalyser()
        ob_ws5 = ws.WordAnalyser()
        ob_ws6 = ws.WordAnalyser()

        print("part 4")

        ob_ws1.analyse_word(token1)
        ob_ws2.analyse_word(token2)
        ob_ws3.analyse_word(token3)
        ob_ws4.analyse_word(token4)
        ob_ws5.analyse_word(token5)
        ob_ws6.analyse_word(token6)

        print("part 5")

        le_frq1 = ob_ws1.get_word_length_frequency()
        le_frq2 = ob_ws2.get_word_length_frequency()
        le_frq3 = ob_ws3.get_word_length_frequency()
        le_frq4 = ob_ws4.get_word_length_frequency()
        le_frq5 = ob_ws5.get_word_length_frequency()
        le_frq6 = ob_ws6.get_word_length_frequency()

        print("part 6")




        plt.plot(le_frq1['val'], le_frq1['frq'], label = 'Richard_II_Shakespeare')
        plt.plot(le_frq2['val'], le_frq2['frq'], label = 'Edward_II_Marlowe' )
        plt.plot(le_frq3['val'], le_frq3['frq'], label = 'Hamlet_Shakespeare' )
        plt.plot(le_frq4['val'], le_frq4['frq'], label = 'Henry_VI_Part1_Shakespeare')
        plt.plot(le_frq5['val'], le_frq5['frq'], label = 'Henry_VI_Part2_Shakespeare')
        plt.plot(le_frq6['val'], le_frq6['frq'], label = 'Jew_of_Malta_Marlowe')
        plt.title('word_length_frequency')
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that you're reading your files in each method, but after you call the first one, you're at the end of the file. You need to `seek` to get back to the start if you're going to use the file again (rather than say, closing and reopening it).

Try adding `self.df_rich.seek(0)` just before each place you read from the `self.df_rich` file (and similar lines for each other file, where you read them).

Comment: You mean to say: 
self.df_rich.seek(0)
self.df_rich = open('Richard_II_Shakespeare.tok')

self.df_edw.seek(0)
self.df_Edw = open('Edward_II_Marlowe.tok')

or are you talking about the main file?